# List of points should result in a polyline with different strokes

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing, polyline

I'm having a list of points. Those should be drawn as a kind of polyline with the possibility to have different colors for each line segment. Also the shape should always fit within a given area (enlarge if its smaller then the area, shrink if its bigger).
I already tried to use a grid with multiple overlaying polylines, one for each color. To have the enlargement/shrinking, I set the stretch property of each polyline to uniform and the horizontal and vertical alignment to center. But this only works if each polyline is of the same size.

```
<Grid>
    <!-- Positive Example -->
    <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Red" Margin="120,50,120,200" Padding="3">
        <Grid>
            <Polyline
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Stroke="Black"
                StrokeThickness="2"
                Stretch="Uniform"
                Points="0,0 10,0 10,-10 0,-10"/>
            <Polyline
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Stroke="YellowGreen"
                StrokeThickness="2"
                Stretch="Uniform"
                Points="0,0 10,0 10,-10"/>    
        </Grid>
    </Border>

    <!-- Negative Example -->
    <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Red" Margin="120,200,120,50" Padding="3">
        <Grid>
            <Polyline
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Stroke="Black"
                StrokeThickness="2"
                Stretch="Uniform"
                Points="0,0 10,0 10,-10 -2,-10"/>
            <Polyline
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Stroke="YellowGreen"
                StrokeThickness="2"
                Stretch="Uniform"
                Points="0,0 10,0 10,-10"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

[image: Code results in this]

What am I missing? Is there a better way to do this? Is there a alternative to polyline, where I can specify different colors for each segment?

Comment: Can you post an image that shows what this scene is *supposed* to look like?  I have no idea from your post how the lines are supposed to appear.

Comment: each line in a polyline cannot have different colors, a polyline just has a `Fill` and `Stroke` used for all the lines. So you have to follow another approach (with some codebehind).

Comment: @MikeStrobel: now you see the result obove. The the green polyline in the lower one should overlay the black line but its not because the black one has 2 more in width

Comment: And when you say you want the lines to enlarge/shrink, do you want the lines to scale, or just the sizes of the boxes you're building with the lines?

Comment: @KingKing: Do you have a suggestion how to do this? I already tried to generate a list of polylines by code and bind this to a ItemsControl. But then it doesn't "zoom" :(

Comment: @MikeStrobel: The red box is a fix space where the visualization should fit to. The resulting shape of the points should be as big as it could be in the red box. This is what in my opinion stretch "uniform" does.

Comment: Let me clarify: if you stretch the entire shape, the thickness of the lines will increase uniformly with the size of the shape.  Is this what you want, or do want the shape to expand but not scale?

Comment: @MikeStrobel: no, the thickness should stay the same. These points are just an example, they could also be more then 100 or less then 1 away from each other. Else that would result in not recognizable shapes.